# App that lets me read my "Saved" Reddit posts offline on Android?

Tags: android, reddit

I have tried many apps but am frustrated as I have yet to find a tool that can allow me to view my "Saved" posts from Reddit to read on my commute.

[image: Reddit save]

Any tips? I have Evernote with the clipping webpage feature and it works for other webpages but not Reddit.

Comment: Try using Pocket, It's free on Google Play.
It has many features such as article view tags.
Can save your Reddit posts.

Comment: What is "Saved"? Is that a particular Reddit feature? Or is it just a web page at a particular URL?

Comment: How can a software know what pages are "saved" and what pages are not? Do you want pages to be saved as static files remaining the same forever, or do you want updates to be saved locally each day, like for podcasts?

Comment: Static. Evernote paid has this feature.

Comment: It's your posts  which you clicked "save" on Reddit. You can view all saved posts at one particular URL.